# How to compute the size of an intersection of two STL sets in C++

Tags: c++, algorithm, stl

I am given two sets (std::set from `<set>`) of which I'd like to know the *size* of the intersection. I could use std::set_intersection from `<algorithm>`, but I have to provide it an output iterator to copy the intersection into some other container.

A straightforward way would be

```
  set<int> s1{1,2,3,4,5};
  set<int> s2{4,5,6,7,8,9,0,1};

  vector<int> v;

  set_intersection(
      s1.begin(), s1.end(), s2.begin(), s2.end(),
      inserter(v, v.begin()));
```

after which v.size() gives the size of the intersection. However, the intersection will have to be stored as well, even though we don't do anything with it.

To avoid that, I tried to implement a dummy output iterator class, which only counts, but it doesn't assign:

```
template<typename T>
class CountingOutputIterator {
 private:
  int* counter_;
  T dummy_;
 public:
  explicit CountingOutputIterator(int* counter) :counter_(counter) {}
  T& operator*() {return dummy_;}
  CountingOutputIterator& operator++() { // ++t
    (*counter_)++;
    return *this;
  }
  CountingOutputIterator operator++(int) { // t++
    CountingOutputIterator ret(*this);
    (*counter_)++;
    return ret;
  }
  bool operator==(const CountingOutputIterator& c) {
    return counter_ == c.counter_; // same pointer
  }
  bool operator!=(const CountingOutputIterator& c) {
    return !operator==(c);
  }
};
```

using which we could do

```
  set<int> s1{1,2,3,4,5};
  set<int> s2{4,5,6,7,8,9,0,1};

  int counter = 0;
  CountingOutputIterator<int> counter_it(&counter);
  set_intersection(
      s1.begin(), s1.end(), s2.begin(), s2.end(), counter_it);
```

after which counter holds the size of the intersection.

This is much more code however. My questions are:

1) Is there a standard (library) way or a standard trick to obtain the size of the intersection without storing the whole intersection?
2) Independent of whether or not there is, is the approach with the custom dummy iterator a good one?

Comment: Seems overly complicated for just identifying the number of common elements. Why not just use a loop?

Comment: Very strange, what is the point of knowing the size when you are never actually going to use the intersection?  Are you thinking about this clearly?  [Read this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: Rather than a custom iterator, it would be simpler to create a custom "container" that has an `insert()` member that counts and use `insert_iterator` with that.

Comment: @HansPassant Why do you find that strange? I can think of many situations. Essentially it is the area of the overlap.

Comment: @JonathanWakely thanks, I'll give it a thought

Comment: @Aldehir It seemed so to me too, however, if you want to write custom code with the same space and time requirements you don't get something less complicates so easily.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It's not difficult to write a loop that moves through the two sets looking for matching elements, or you could do this, which is much simpler than a custom iterator:

```
struct Counter
{
  struct value_type { template<typename T> value_type(const T&) { } };
  void push_back(const value_type&) { ++count; }
  size_t count = 0;
};

template<typename T1, typename T2>
size_t intersection_size(const T1& s1, const T2& s2)
{
  Counter c;
  set_intersection(s1.begin(), s1.end(), s2.begin(), s2.end(), std::back_inserter(c));
  return c.count;
}
```

Comment: For me to compile it (g++ 4.8.4) I had to make Counter as a struct a template of T, and nest a typedef for value_type inside it: using value_type = T;

Comment: Ah yes, good point. I've updated the answer with an alternative fix that still means `Counter` doesn't need to be a template: define a `value_type` that can be constructed from anything.

Comment: What if I want to parallelize it though? With `std::execution::par` that is. :|

Answer (score 4):

It isn't very hard to write a function that does this. [This](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/set_intersection/) shows how `set_intersection` is done [although the actual implementation may of course be subtly different]

So we could just take that code, and modify it a little bit:

```
template <class InputIterator1, class InputIterator2>
  size_t set_intersection_size (InputIterator1 first1, InputIterator1 last1,
                                InputIterator2 first2, InputIterator2 last2)
{
  size_t result = 0;
  while (first1!=last1 && first2!=last2)
  {
    if (*first1<*first2) ++first1;
    else if (*first2<*first1) ++first2;
    else {
      result++;
      ++first1; ++first2;
    }
  }
  return result;
}
```

Although in my experience, when you want to know how many are in the intersection, you typically sooner or later want to know WHICH elements too.

Answer (score 3):

You could do this:

```
auto common = count_if(begin(s1), end(s1), [&](const auto& x){ return s2.find(x) != end(s2); });
```

It's not optimally efficient but should be fast enough for most purposes.

Comment: shouldn't there be a comparison to s2.end() ?

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf yep, oops. Fixed.

Comment: Which has worse complexity -- `O(n log n)` against `O(n)`.

Comment: Thanks. However, that has a higher computational complexity, namely $n\log n$ versus $m + \log n$, where $n$ is the size of the sets and $m$ of their intersection.

Comment: @doetoe Yep, I edited to mention that after posting. This solution favours conciseness over efficiency. Mats Petersson's answer is the most efficient approach, or your custom iterator solution.

Comment: @doetoe This is the sort of thing that Eric Niebler's proposed [Range v3](https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3) library extension would be great for.

Comment: If s2 is much bigger than s1, the complexity n1*log(n2) can be smaller than n1+n2.

Answer (score 3):

You can simplify the usage of your approach a fair bit:

```
struct counting_iterator
{
    size_t count;
    counting_iterator& operator++() { ++count; return *this; }

    struct black_hole { void operator=(T) {} };
    black_hole operator*() { return black_hole(); }

    // other iterator stuff may be needed
};

size_t count = set_intersection(
  s1.begin(), s1.end(), s2.begin(), s2.end(), counting_iterator()).count;
```

Comment: Good point, thanks. I had started like that, but then I thought I wouldn't have access to the iterator as passed to set_intersection. But of course a copy is simply returned.